# Attacking with shields? Who does that?

Tags: dark-souls

I recently found out that if equipped in right hand slot, shield can be uesd as a weapon. It deals much lower damage and attack is pretty slow. The only case I think this could be useful is if all other weapons suddenly break and are no longer usable without repair. But I just started, so I don't know much.

Is there some benefit to attacking with shields? Maybe there is some specific shield that is particularly good in role of a main weapon?

Comment: LobosJR did a shield only speedrun in less than 2 hours! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHPHrLUD9Vk

Answer (score 5):

All shields deal *strike damage*, to which some enemies are more susceptible (skeletons). This might have a limited use early in the game when a weapon with strike damage might not be available/found yet. But frankly, a club can be bought from undead merchant pretty early on.

I've never found a reason to use a shield as main weapon.

Comment: Now this comment is going to be only presumption, but I think anything that can be equipped in hand (wieldable items) can be attacked with. I would guess that this is how the game is designed internally, by making eg a shield as wieldable, it gains some properties/behaviours that all wieldable items share, which in this case is the ability to attack. For that same reason, you can defend with all weapons and even sorcerer wands (not very useful either). My point is that shield attack probably doesn't have any intended use, merely it's a result of how the game is designed.

Comment: I think it is more that the developers WANT people to try quirky, unexpected builds. It's part of the charm of the game.

Comment: I realise this is an old post, but wanted to chime in: some shield attacks count as blocking, so you can effectively 'cross-counter' with them. And two-handing a shield increases its stability, making any mad dashes for survival easier. Then there's the infamous Chaos Bonewheel...